# Oracle 19c Compatible - Powerbuilder

Tags: oracle, powerbuilder

One of our application build by powerbuilder 6.5 and it was currently connected Oracle 11.2.0.4 version. We are planning to migrate the 19c oracle. So will it be compatible 19c Oracle?

And we need to know if the Appeaon 2017 R3 1858 will support/compatible for 19C oracle?

Comment: What do Powerbuilder and Appeaon say? Do they support Oracle 19c? Why would you trust this or any other forum over the vendor's own documentation or certifications?

Comment: I got the answer from Appeon 19c is support only 2017 R3 1915 or 2019 version only

Comment: PB2017 R3  MR 1915+ or PB2019. Visit the Appeon Community BB at https://community.appeon.com/index.php/qna/q-a/pb-17-and-oracle-19c/voted

Answer (score 1):

We are working on a similar project to migrate Oracle9i database to Oracle 19c and the front end application is Powerbuilder 6.5

As part of the POC we connected the application to Oracle 19c application using Oracle 10g client on the server. With this setup we saw Powerbuilder 6.5 was compatible with Oracle 19c and have not faced any issues so far.

Comment: We are at the similar phase migrating Oracle 11g to 19c, but facing error "ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied Oracle 19c" while doing same. Connected the Oracle 19c DB with 11g client and got success with tnsping but not able to connect PB 6.5.